# CRM2011: Silverlight not fired when form save, got JavaScript Error: SCRIPT16389

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a silverlight webresource on the form, in the form onload event, I use javascript to call the method in the silverlight.

When open a form or click refresh the form, the silverlight method be fired which is correct.

But if update the record and click save, the form reload but the silverlight not fired, I got this javascript error:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error:
SCRIPT16389**

This is my javascript function to call silverlight:

```
function Test() {
debugger;
var sl1 = document.getElementById('WebResource_SLTextBox'); //the weresource was put on the form already
sl1.Content.scriptableLable.TestAlert(); //the silverlight only do one thing which is pop up a message box. here got javascript error

}
```

---

I add a javascript alert for test purpose and it make it works! After click the "OK" button on the alert box, the silverlight method fired.

The problem is I can't leave this alert on the page. It only for testing, but if I remove the alert, the silverlight not fired. :(

Answer (score 0):

I modify my code, call the silverlight method in silverlight control loaded event instead of call it from form onload javascript.

This way worked.